# Changing Camel Log level at runtime using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I created a Spring Boot application utilizing Camel.  In a route I am using the Log component as follows:

```
        from("direct:start")
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "com.somepackage","Request: ${body}")
            .process(myProcessor)
            .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "com.somepackage","Response: ${body}");
```

In my application.yml I have set up logging as follows:

```
 logging:
  level:
    com.somepackage: INFO
```

When I start the application the logging doesn't happen due to it being a lower level.  Using the Spring Boot Actuator to change the level:

```
 (POST)   /actuator/loggers/com.somepackage
Request:
{
    "configuredLevel": "DEBUG"
}
```

and then verify the change:

```
     (GET)   /actuator/loggers/com.somepackage
Response:
    {
        "configuredLevel": "DEBUG",
        "effectiveLevel": "DEBUG"
    }
```

But the logging still does not happen.  It does not happen even when level set to TRACE.
However if I set the logging level in the application file to DEBUG and then compile/run the application the logging for that Log component happens and it is responsive.  I can set the level higher to exclude or lower to include using Actuator.

The standard logging of Spring Boot is responsive to the log level changes from the Actuator no matter what the level is set to in the application file but the Camel Log component is responsive only if the level set in the Log component is equal to or higher at startup.  Anyone have a thought or solution on this?

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error and tried a few other camel versions. camel 3.5.0 and below worked for me.

Edit:
I opened a bugticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16705
It will be fixed in Version 3.11.0